# Vue 3 Storybook: (PrimeVue) Component not display

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

Currently I am working a bit with Vue Storybook (Vue Js 3) in combination with an UI Framework [primevue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/). However, I set up everything correctly and without issues, still I can't see my component in the browser. It should be rendered normally.

Regarding the documentation, I just need to write a .vue and a .stories.js file, to display my component.

main.js

---

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

const app = createApp(App);


app.component('Breadcrumb', Breadcrumb);
app.use(PrimeVue,{ripple: true});
```

List.vue

---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Breadcrumb :home="home" :model="items" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Breadcrumb from "primevue/breadcrumb";

export default {
  name: "List",
  components: {
    Breadcrumb,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      home: {
        icon: "pi pi-home",
        to: "/",
      },
      items: [
        { label: "Computer" },
        { label: "Notebook" },
        { label: "Accessories" },
        { label: "Backpacks" },
        { label: "Item" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

List.stories.js

---

```
import List from "./List.vue";

export default {
  title: "List",
  component: List,
};

// export const actionsData = {
//   onPinTask: action("pin-task"),
//   onArchiveTask: action("archiveTask"),
// };

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
    components: { List },
    props: Object.keys(argTypes),
    template:
      '<List />',
  });
export const ListDefault = Template.bind({});
```

Anyone an idea, where the issue is? I can see it inside the Storybook Sidemenu.
[image: localhost]

Answer (score 2):

VUE3+ts+primevue

In my case i edited the preview.js

```
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3'
import { globalComponentsRegistry } from '../src/utils/globalComponentsRegistry';
import { PRIMEVUE_COMPONENTS } from '../src/utils/primevue/index';

import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';

app.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true });

globalComponentsRegistry(PRIMEVUE_COMPONENTS, app)

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

I have an utils function that install components on my main app **globalComponentsRegistry()** I m using it for storybook too. Heres the code:

```
/**
 * Helper to register all Primevue components dynamically as: ...app.component('TabMenu', TabMenu);
 */
export const globalComponentsRegistry = (components: any, context: any) => {
  Object.entries(components).forEach(([keyName, definition]) => {
    const componentName = keyName;
    context.component(componentName, definition);
  });
};
```

It receives an object of all componets 'PRIMEVUE_COMPONENTS' and the app instance (same case for storybook and main-app)

```
import TabMenu from 'primevue/tabmenu';
import Knob from 'primevue/knob';

export const PRIMEVUE_COMPONENTS = {
  TabMenu: TabMenu,
  Knob: Knob,
  ...
};
```

No i can see my custom components on storybook. In this test prime knob component.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is with your **main.js** file. I struggled with mine too but eventually I have it up and running. Your main.js is an entry point to storybook app and you need to config it differently from your main application. If you look at the image below, you'll notice **app** is imported from @storybook/vue3. That's the main point of the confusion when it comes to integrating with third party library.

[image: main.js file]

Also take note of your css files. I have gone ahead to import all the css files I needed for my application. If you're using less or scss, do check up on [storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/configure/styling-and-css) on how to manage those. Ciao.

For those who like to copy and paste the code:

```js
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';

app.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true });

export const decorators = [(story) => ({
  components: {
    story,
  },
  template: '<story />'
})];

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "⌃on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
   matchers: {
    color: /(background|color)$/i/,
    date: /Date$/,
   }
  },
  decorators
}
```

Comment: Please paste real text (as code block) in the future. Being able to copy and paste text is important, and your image makes this impossible.

Comment: @Pwdr oh sorry about that. I see where you're coming from. Thanks for pointing this out. Regards.